# Mysql TIMEDIFF NULL values

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

I have a two TIME datatype columns table in `mysql`,     `ver 5.5.31` on DEBIAN.  Need to get a time difference in seconds.  Have used this query but just get `NULL` values.  Any idea what is wrong with it?  My query:

```
Select TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, TIME(a.timestamp_end),     TIME(a.timestamp_start)) as total_time From  timestamp
```

However,  what I get is `NULL`,  instead of the expected `INT` that represents seconds between two times.  Actually the data type for the columns is `TIME`,  and this a sample of data stored: `07:11:40` `07:11:56`.  In the case of this row,  I should get 16 instead of `NULL`.

Comment: @SamD I've just checked and works great.  That is.  You gave the perfect answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT (SECOND(a.timestamp_end) - SECOND(a.timestamp_start)) as total_time 
FROM timestamp
```

Comment: However I would like to know why the ``TIMESTAMPDIFF`` is not working.

Comment: I remeber this being a bug in MySQL 5.0 where TIMESTAMPDIFF  did not work with second this bug may still be in place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
 SELECT TimestampDiff(SECOND, a.timestamp_end, a.timestamp_start) AS somename FROM table
```

Comment: excuse me,  I thought I was commenting on @SamD.

Comment: @waswwm,  Before using the ``TIME`` wrap,  I used as you point,  but received a NULL instead of a valid value.